# WPF: Multiple XAML files that share the same code behind file

Tags: wpf, layout, share, code-behind

I want to create an application where the user navigates through pages that are placed inside a frame element. The problem is that one page can have different layouts which basically provide the same functionality. There can be a few buttons or input controls more or less per layout, but they all should share the same code behind file.

In Windows Forms, I used to place all elements (the layout) on the same form and then hide/show the controls I required, but that's a very ugly solution and I was hoping that WPF provided something more convenient here.

I tried to create 2 Pages, deleted their respective .cs files and set their "x:Class" attribute to a custom .cs file, but that results in compiler errors (ambiguous calls to InitializeComponent() ).

So can I have multiple pages that share the same code?

Comment: Why not separate the common parts into a shared codebase? Or what kind of code is there behind these pages and how does the layout differ?

Comment: The layout varies in colors, fonts, position of elements, number of elements, and even functionality the elements provide. The main "problem" is that the layouts do not differ enough to justify separated pages.
The code behind can be quite excessive because some pages may control one or more hardware devices that are linked to the application. Although the control classes for the devices are in their own code files, the call logic can also be quite large and should remain in one place. Moving it to its own code file is of course possible, but also more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the logic from the code-behind class to a view model class. This pattern is known as Model-View-ViewModel and is *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based user interface applications.

There are plenty of online tutorials about it and this one should provide a good starting point for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx.

Once you have understood the pattern and implemented your application logic in a view model class, you could then simply set the `DataContext` property of both pages to the same view model:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

A code-behind class is simply a partial class, i.e. it is partial definition of the `Page` that you define in XAML and therefore you cannot "share" this one between several different pages.

Partial classes are just a way of splitting the definition of a class across several different source files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods.